# Prove $\frac1{\sqrt{(x_n)}}$ converges to $\frac1{\sqrt{(x)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

So far I have:

$$\vert\frac1{\sqrt{(x_n)}} - \frac1{\sqrt{(x)}}\vert = \vert\frac{\sqrt{(x)}-\sqrt{(x_n)}}{\sqrt{(x)}\sqrt{(x_n)}}\vert = \frac{\sqrt{(x)} + \sqrt{(x_n)}}{\sqrt{(x)}\sqrt{(x_n)}}$$

From here I am not exactly sure what to do. I know I want this fraction to somehow be less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: My attempt, use the fact that every convergent sequence is bounded. So assume $\sqrt{x_{n}} < a$. Then we have $\frac{x_n-x}{\sqrt{x_n}\sqrt{x}} < \frac{x_n-x}{a^2}$. And then use the hypothesis.

Comment: I meant to write $\sqrt{x_n}>a$ for some $a$ in the reals.

Comment: $|a-b| \not = a+b$

Comment: This is a very serious mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $x_n \to x$, and assuming $x >1$ (the proof can be modified slightly to work for all $x >0$):

Define $C = \sqrt{x(x-1)}(x + \sqrt{x-1})$

Fix any $\epsilon > 0$. There exists an $N_1$ such that $\forall (n \ge N_1): |x_n - x| < 1$, and there exists an $N_2$ such that $\forall (n \ge N_2): |x_n - x | < C\epsilon $. Choose $N = \max \{ N_1, N_2 \}$.

Now, we have

$$\left |\dfrac {1}{\sqrt{x_n}} - \dfrac {1}{\sqrt x} \right| = \left | \dfrac {x-x_n}{\sqrt{xx_n}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_n})} \right |$$

For any $n \ge N$ we have in particular $n \ge N_1$, so $|x_n - x| < 1$, therefore $\sqrt{xx_n}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_n}) \ge \sqrt{x(x-1)}(x + \sqrt{x-1}) = C$, so $\dfrac {1}{\sqrt{xx_n}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_n})} \le \dfrac 1C$.

Intuitively, this inequality is true because $x_n \in (x-1, x+1)$, and since the $\sqrt {\cdot}$ function is monotonically increasing, $\sqrt{xx_n}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_n})$ must be greater than or equal to the same expression with $x-1$ substituted for $x_n$.

Therefore:

$$\left |\dfrac {1}{\sqrt{x_n}} - \dfrac {1}{\sqrt x} \right| = \left | \dfrac {x-x_n}{\sqrt{xx_n}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_n})} \right | \le \dfrac {C\epsilon}{C} = \epsilon$$

The result is proved.

Answer (score 1):

on any interval $]a;+\infty[$ with $a>0$ one has for $x,y > a$

$$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt y}\right| < \frac{1}{2 a^{3/2}} |x-y|$$

so this should allow you to conclude the argument ;)

The reason for the bound is just because the derivate of $x^{1/2}$ is $-\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}$ which is bounded on any interval $]a;+\infty[$